# error: 'not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 'b-1 in a')' when using jQuery-UI Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, autocomplete

A bit of background: I'm building an Autocomplete search field for WordPress, which will contain Trade names (A hierarchal custom taxonomy, essentially Categories), however I don't think this is a WordPress issue any more. I originally asked a question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154693/jquery-ui-autocomplete-showing-all-results?noredirect=1#comment222899_154693), where the answerer gave me a very good understanding of how WP and AJAX work together. I then read up and integrated [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), and read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete) which also helped me out a lot.

However, I now have a console error whenever I try to search for something:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.length')
    map (jquery.js, line 2)
    (anonymous function) (autocomplete.js, line 5)
    j (jquery.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery.js, line 2)
    x (jquery.js, line 4)
    b (jquery.js, line 4)
```

[Screenshot of the error](http://cl.ly/Wbin), to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

And here is my PHP code (in functions.php):

```
wp_enqueue_script("autocomplete", get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/autocomplete.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-form', 'json2' ), false, true );
wp_localize_script("autocomplete", "MyAjax_object", array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'myajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax_nonce_val' ),
    'action' => 'myajax-submit'
));
function get_my_suggestions() {
    // This function should query the database and get results as an array of rows:
    // GET the recieved data: 'term' (what has been typed by the user)
    $term = $_GET['term'];
    $trades = get_terms( 'trade', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $tradesList = '["' . implode( '","', $trades ) . '"]';

    // echo JSON to page  and exit.
    $response = $_GET["callback"]."(". json_encode($trades) .")";  
    echo $response;  
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'get_my_suggestions' );
```

and JavaScript (autocomplete.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main-search-field").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {  
            jQuery.getJSON( MyAjax_object.ajaxurl + "?callback=?&action=myajax-submit", request, function( data ) {
                response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                    jQuery.each( item, function( i, val ) {
                        val.label = val.whatever; // build result for autocomplete from suggestion array data
                    } );
                    return item;
                } ) );
            } );  
        }, 
        minLength: 1,
        appendTo: ".search-container"
    }); 
});
```

Does anyone know why I get that error? The JavaScript loads fine - it adds in the markup for the suggestions list, but it's empty. Also, I've noticed that whenever I search for something in the input box, a class, `ui-autocomplete-loading` is added to the input box, but never disappears like it should do when the results are loaded in. Not sure if that's important but it might help someone out.

Thanks for any help :)

**EDIT:** It's just been pointed out to me that in the PHP I was passing the wrong variable to `json_encode`. I've fixed that and now the error is as follows:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'Accountants' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating 'b-1 in a')
s (jquery.js, line 2)
each (jquery.js, line 2)
(anonymous function) (autocomplete.js, line 6)
map (jquery.js, line 2)
(anonymous function) (autocomplete.js, line 5)
j (jquery.js, line 2)
fireWith (jquery.js, line 2)
x (jquery.js, line 4)
b (jquery.js, line 4)
```

Again, here is a screenshot to make it clearer. http://cl.ly/WbaN. I don't even know what this error means, let alone how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in the way you build the response on the get_my_suggestion() function.

You should build an array of objects similar to this

```
[
 {
    value: "value1",
    label: "label1",
  },
  {
    value: "value2",
    label: "label2",
  },
]
```

So first check that the output of that function is formatted this way.